# JavaFX - Why do buttons sometimes shrink?

Tags: java, button, javafx

In javaFX, why do my button sometimes randomly shrink when I hover over them?

[image]

Why is this happening and how do I stop it.

Here is my code for the button depicted, but I don't know if you need it. It seems to happen to other buttons also and it dosn't always happen to the same button.

```
btnNext = new Button(">");
    btnNext.setOnAction(e -> {
        switch (view) {
            case MONTH:
                setDisplay(target.plusMonths(1));
                break;
            case WEEK:
                setDisplay(target.plusWeeks(1));
                break;
        }
    });
```

This only happens AFTER I click it and then leave. When the program first starts, it is the normal size.

Comment: What's the parent of the buttons? What does `setDisplay` do? Did you add a stylesheet? (Or short: create a [mcve])

Comment: The parent is just an HBox. `setDisplay` isn't important, because it does it on all other buttons that do other things. No stylesheets.

Answer (score 2):

When a control shrinks, it's usually a good sign that something else is stealing the space away from it. Under normal conditions, the `Scene` would ask all the descendant nodes how much space it needs to render itself - this is what `prefWidth` and `prefHeight` do.

When there is a space constraint, most `Pane` subclasses (recall that `Pane` subclasses manages their children based on certain rules) will try to reduce the size of one or more children. If you do not want a particular `Node` to shrink below what is its calculated size, then you *must* specify a `minWidth` and/or `minHeight`, or set them to `USE_PREF_SIZE`. Setting either or both of them to `USE_PREF_SIZE` tells the parent that this node must not shrink.

However, if you specify `USE_PREF_SIZE` for all nodes, then the parent will be in trouble - it has been told to shrink but it couldn't shrink anything. I do not know exactly what will happen, but most likely, the whole UI going to *look* weird.